# Hover over a png with a border radius in IE9 messing with transparency

Tags: html, css

I'm running into a problem on IE9. And I'm not sure what causes it.
On hover / selected the thumbnail is showing a white to gray gradient box around the transparent png, there is also a border radius around the thumbnail.

Any clues as to what I should be looking for?

Problem example:

[image]

What it should be:

[image]

```
.gyges .tp-thumb-img-wrap {
  border-radius: 45px;
}
.gyges .tp-thumb.selected .tp-thumb-img-wrap {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59);
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, images would not help us much. You also need to post your HTML. This question is incomplete unless you are able to create a demo of the issue.

Comment: @ManojKumar Why do need to inspect the HTML when dealing with such a CSS bug?

Comment: if i recall correctly, IE9 only supports transparency for PNG-24 and not PNG-8. Could  be the issue. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/294714 also, see here: https://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/

Comment: Probably related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188024/how-to-fix-ie-rendering-of-border-radius-combined-with-box-shadow

Comment: @feeela It is always better for OP to show the demo. Just my suggestion for him. I was not aware of the duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from someone else I've found a solution to our problem. 
The hover/selected items now show correctly on IE9.
I was provided with this code, not quite sure yet as to what it actually does, but it does the trick for this case.

```
    .gyges .tp-thumb:hover .tp-thumb-img-wrap,
    .gyges .tp-thumb.selected .tp-thumb-img-wrap 
    {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }
```

Thank you for your help & suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the rendering-engine know that the `border-radius` declaration persists, even when the thumbnail is hovered over:

```
.gyges .tp-thumb-img-wrap,
.gyges .tp-thumb.selected .tp-thumb-img-wrap {
  border-radius: 45px;
}

.gyges .tp-thumb.selected .tp-thumb-img-wrap {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59);
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, this doesn't do anything. 
I've tried a couple of variations, but all have the same result.
Even removing everything from the .selected / :hover css rules, this happens. But as stated in my question, I have no clue what is causing it, it might not be css that is the problem. I just don't know.